# How to connect django settings.py with mongo db?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

This is my code to connect my django application with mongo db atlas.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': username,
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://%s:%s@save4thpillar-sonvx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'% (username, password),
        'PORT': 27017,
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f5b85e69a60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 File "/home/nadeem/Documents/backendAPI/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 183, in select_servers
    selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "/home/nedeem/Documents/backendAPI/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
```

Kindly help me to connect.